# Jenkins cache artifact for long running module

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, build

We have a Jenkins build that builds many OSGI modules, then copies the artifacts to our development server.  There is one module that generates our POJOs for all tables and it takes a very long time compared to the rest of the build.  Is there a way to create a build that stores this Jar (whether always or through the use of a flag)?  This module is not frequently updated, but when it is all these POJOs need to be regenerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a build that stores this Jar (whether always or through the use of a flag)?

You can use a caching mechanism to store the artifact and reuse it in subsequent builds.
You can use a dedicated artifact repository (like [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/blog/what-is-artifactory-jfrog/) or [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products/sonatype-nexus-repository)) or a simple file system storage.

```bash
+---------------------------------------------+
| Jenkins Build                               |
|                                             |
|  +------------+     +-------------------+   |
|  | Other      |     | Long Running      |   |
|  | Modules    |     | Module (POJO Gen) |   |
|  +------------+     +-------------------+   |
|         |                   |               |
|         | Artifact          | Artifact      |
|         | Copy              | Copy          |
|         +-----------------> | (with caching)|
|                             |               |
+-----------------------------+---------------+
```

Introduce a flag or environment variable (e.g., `CACHE_POJO_ARTIFACT`) that controls whether the long-running module should be built or fetched from cache.

- If the flag is set (and a cached version is available), skip the build process for the long-running module and use the cached artifact.
- If the flag is not set, proceed with the build and update the cache with the new artifact.

```bash
# Pseudo bash script for caching mechanism
CACHE_POJO_ARTIFACT=${CACHE_POJO_ARTIFACT:-false}

if [ "$CACHE_POJO_ARTIFACT" = true ] && [ -f "path/to/cached/artifact.jar" ]; then
    echo "Using cached POJO artifact"
    # Code to fetch and use the cached artifact
else
    echo "Building POJO module"
    # Code to build the POJO module
    # Code to update the cache with the new artifact
fi
```

Configure the Jenkins job to accept the cache control parameter (`CACHE_POJO_ARTIFACT`). Make sure the Jenkins job has the necessary permissions and configuration to access the cache storage.

When you need to rebuild the POJO module (e.g., after updates), trigger the build with the cache flag disabled
For regular builds where the POJO module has not changed, enable the cache flag to use the cached artifact.

---

As an alternative, you also have the [Jenkins Job cacher plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jobcacher/), designed to cache files between runs of a Jenkins pipeline. You would avoid a dependency on an external binary referential.

In your `Jenkinsfile`, you would use the `cache` block provided by `jobcacher` to cache the output of the long-running module:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        booleanParam(name: 'USE_CACHE', defaultValue: false, description: 'Use cached POJO artifact if available')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Long Running Module') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (params.USE_CACHE) {
                        // Use jobcacher to fetch from cache
                        cache(path: 'path/to/pojo/artifacts', id: 'pojo-cache-id') {
                            echo "Cache is missing or outdated, rebuilding POJOs..."
                            // Steps to rebuild POJOs
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "Rebuilding POJOs without using cache..."
                        // Steps to rebuild POJOs without caching
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Other stages
    }
}
```

You need to define a unique cache ID (`id: 'pojo-cache-id'` in the example) which is used to identify and retrieve the correct cache.

Comment: Thanks!  Currently not using Pipelines, will I need to convert this build into a Pipeline for this to work, the second solution looks like the easiest.